# Is it acceptable to activate microphone by default in an app with a voice chat feature?

Tags: user-communication

I'm working on a collaborative app which features voice chat as a feature. The first time time the user visits the app they'll be asked for permission to use their microphone. Is it acceptable to activate it by default thereafter for voice communication purposes? There's an option to mute the mic, but the user is expected to know that the mic is active, with voice communication between themselves and group members.

Comment: Is there a visual indicator of the microphone status? How come the user is expected to know that the mic is active?

Comment: @MichaelLai I expect them to know based on the fact that 1) on their first visit they were asked permission to activate it 2) they'll hear the other people in the group talking. The voice chat is a major feature of the app.

Comment: Sue, but are they told that the microphone will be activated by default in the future? Also, is the option to mute the mic very prominent? One thing I have learnt about users is that they forget most things that they read, so don't assume that showing them something means they will read or understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Is voice chat the primary feature? In other words, do I come here to participate in chat or is chat something I can do along with other things?

If the application is specifically for such collaboration, I would say you can activate the mic by default because that's what they opened the application for. If I turn the TV to CNN, I expect to see CNN. If it's not primarily a chat app, then the user should choose to participate each time.

Comment: Alright, I think Im clear then. Because the app is a collaborative app where people get on it collaborate, voice chat is a major part of it.

Comment: I still like @MichaelLai 's idea of having a visual indicator of the microphone's status, and the option to mute it. People would need this functionality anyway - in case they want to stop chatting via the app and start talking to someone next to them about something confidential.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow yeah that makes sense. I'll make the mute button available up front. Thanks for advice everyone.